# Attempting to connect to Excel spreadsheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, connection-string

I am trying to pull a bunch of data from a spreadsheet, however I am not able to make a successful connection in my C# code. B

Below is the connection string and the code that I am using to make the connection. The goal of the program is to pull the data from the spreadsheet and deposit it into a SQL database. I cannot get past the connection.open() command, however without receiveing this error message:

"External table is not in the expected format"

```
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nearod\Desktop\TestLoad.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [SQL AgentUnique ID Test Load$]";
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    counter++;

                    //Access db values
                    string compCode = "";
                    string agId = "";
                    string fName = "";
                    string lName = "";
                    string nameSuffix = "";


                    compCode = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    agId = reader.GetString(1);
                    fName = reader.GetString(2);
                    lName = reader.GetString(3);
                    nameSuffix = reader.GetString(4);

                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(companyCode);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(agentID);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(firstName);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(lastName);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(suffix);

                    //Initialize connection objects
                    cm = Dts.Connections["QUAHILSQ03"];
                    sqlConn = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
                    sqlComm = new SqlCommand("AgentResourcesU01.dbo.sp_AgentIdAprCheck", sqlConn);
                    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //Execute stored procedure
                    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
                OleDbConnection.ReleaseObjectPool();
            }
```

Comment: BTW You should be able to load a set of data straight into SQL server from MS Access with a suitably structured query.

Comment: I need to call a stored procedure to sort the data properly. Can you do this in Access?

Comment: You can certainly sort the data in MS Access. You can also use the ACE drivers to sort an Excel recordset. In Access, the nearest equivalent to a stored procedure is a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *.xlsx, you need the Ace drivers: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
 Data Source=C:\Users\nearod\Desktop\TestLoad.xlsx;
 Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this a long while back.  It's in WebForms, but the .cs file shows you want you need:
[converting an excel spreadsheet to a dataset, datatable and multi-dimensional array](http://naspinski.net/post/Converting-an-Excel-Spreedsheet-to-a-DatSet2c-Datatable-and-Multi-Dimensioanl-Array.aspx)

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+FileToConvert+";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
try
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    //this next line assumes that the file is in default Excel format with Sheet1 as the first sheet name, adjust accordingly
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(ds);//now you have your dataset ds now filled with the data and ready for manipulation
    // do stuff
}
```